# Particular index photo downloading takes long time to wait

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

I user to display photo gallery in uicollectionview.

Here is my collection view didselectitem code.

IN my array I hold 500 images.

When I select any images its load too much time. I think all 500 images download first and display??

Can you help me ?

I used NYTPhotoviewer.

Is there anything wrong in code ?

```
 (void)updateImagesOnPhotosViewController:(NYTPhotosViewController *)photosViewController afterDelayWithPhotos:(NSArray *)photos
 {
    CGFloat updateImageDelay = 1.0;
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(updateImageDelay * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        int p = 0;
        for (NYTExamplePhoto *photo in photos) {
            if (!photo.image) {
                // Photo credit: Nic Lehoux
                NSLog(@"Images Array %@",[arrayimage objectAtIndex:p]);
                    photo.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[arrayimage objectAtIndex:p]]]];
                    [photosViewController updateImageForPhoto:photo];

                p++;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you using dispatch after? Your array contains image URLs, not images

Comment: Yes my array contains live image URL So what should I do?

Comment: Your code is written to delay, why?